# Huge performance lack in emscripten code

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

it's 2:50 AM here and after a hectic day I found something strange. I do my best to give a picture of my problem.

I wrote these two pieces of code in `C++` and `JavaScript`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    clock_t tStart = clock();

    int result = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < 1000000000;a++) {
        result += a;
    }

    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  return 1;
}
```

And:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

var result = 0;

for(var a = 0;a < 1000000000;a++) {
    result += a;
}

var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
console.log('Time taken: ' + (time/1000) + 's');
```

Both of them do the same thing (I hope so)

After generating `./a.out.js` using the latest version of emscripten, I found something weird:
[image: the result of executing both codes]

The execution time of the emscripten code is really slower than the manually written JavaScript code. What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the javascript generated by emscripten?

Comment: @SimpleJ No, I do believe it's kinda useless.

Comment: I don't know much about emscripten, but I would assume you would get more answers by comparing the outputted javascript to your handmade javascript then by comparing your handmade javascript and C++.

Comment: @SimpleJ Not bad. I will do it tomorrow :-)

Comment: You should also try posting to the emscripten-discuss Google Group, they are very responsive https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/emscripten-discuss

Comment: V8 does a lot more optimization than naive c++, not sure how good the asm compiler is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

node.js lacks most of the real asm.js performance tweaks that make emscripten fast.  Instead of trying it with node, try it in firefox or chrome.

The issue is that node.js tends to lag behind chrome's V8 version, so features (or optimizations) that go into Chrome may take quite awhile to make it into V8.  I don't actually know how long, but the asm.js optimizations are new enough that when I last tried it in early April, 2014 it was significantly slower on the command line with node.js than in the browser with Chrome, and Firefox was faster still.

Comment: Meaning it's the problem of NodeJS in this case?

Comment: More or less, probably so.  I did a benchmark for a build of our technology at GradeCam that took 122 seconds in node.js and 24 seconds in firefox

Comment: I doubt this, using emscripten 1.16 the default compile (e.g., no optimization switches, no header includes, etc) runs faster than native compiles (node 0.10.21, emscripten 1.16). This seems more likely to be a bug in the toolchain used, see my below post.

Comment: @Trevor it all depends on what you are doing.  Our toolchain is set up correctly, but what we're doing requires a huge amount of compiler optimizations that aren't possible in asm.js.  Believe me when I say that I've spent many hours testing different toolchain options to make sure this is true.

In addition, the Firefox team told me that they expect in ideal situations that asm.js should "only" be about 2x as slow as native.  In normal cases a complex C app will never be faster in emscripten than in native code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have a bug somewhere in your compile toolchain. Make sure its not accidentally including the system libraries/headers instead of emscripten's choice.  Also make sure you're not accidently using your systems clang.

If you do emcc -v test.cpp (assuming test.cpp is your file your compiling) it should tell you exactly what headers, llvm/clang and node its going to rely on.  Below you can see the emcc default compile actually runs faster than out-of-the-box clang native c code (this may seem surprising but V8 does runtime optimizations, C++ does not.)

```
slcmew-nmx2499:Downloads trevor.linton$ gcc test.cpp
slcmew-nmx2499:Downloads trevor.linton$ ./a.out
Time taken: 2.33s
slcmew-nmx2499:Downloads trevor.linton$ emcc test.cpp
slcmew-nmx2499:Downloads trevor.linton$ node a.out.js
Time taken: 1.17s
slcmew-nmx2499:Downloads trevor.linton$
```

Finally make sure you're using the latest and greatest ./emsdk update and then ./emsdk install latest-64bit.  This was tested with node 0.10.21 and emscripten 1.16 on MacOS X Mavericks.

Comment: There may be some simple applications where this is the case, but most of the time it will not be.  Even the Firefox team has indicated this.  There are a lot of compile optimizations that aren't possible (yet) in emscripten.  I suspect that the newer your node version the better results you'll get also.